# How to get the first row of table in yii2 with where condition?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

> I need to get the first row of table with where condition.

```
(new Query())
        ->select('*')
        ->from('stock_in')
        ->where("user_id = '$request_user_id'")
        ->andWhere("product_id = '$product_id'")
        ->andWhere("remaining_quantity > '0'")
        ->one();
```

Comment: strange  .. 3 upvote for  thsi question and 3 upvote  for the answer  of the same user  ...  and nothing for the right answer  for another user  ..very strange ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yes i got my answer.Use Limit there

```
(new Query())
        ->select('*')
        ->from('stock_in')
        ->where("user_id = '$request_user_id'")
        ->andWhere("product_id = '$product_id'")
        ->andWhere("remaining_quantity > '0'")
        ->limit('1')
        ->one();
```

Comment: if you use LIMIT without ORDER BY.. MySQL could randomly return 1 record matching the where.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the result of a query you should use `limit()`.

```
(new Query())
    ->select('*')
    ->from('stock_in')
    ->where("user_id = '$request_user_id'")
    ->andWhere("product_id = '$product_id'")
    ->andWhere("remaining_quantity > '0'")
    ->limit(2)
    ->all();
```

Documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#limit-offset

Comment: if you use LIMIT without ORDER BY.. MySQL could randomly return 1 record matching the where.

Comment: Sir it return the first record accordingly when use limit(1)